# Making a button action work across multiple classes in Java

Tags: java, jbutton

I'm making a calculator in Java, but I can't seem to get a button's actionListener to make things change in 4 other classes. What I want is for the button to change the text in the program from English to Spanish. My program consists of 5 classes and I want the language in all of the JLabels, buttons and menus changed in each.

This is my button listener code:

```
btnLanguage = new JButton("Language");
    btnLanguage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnAddition.setText("Añadir");
            btnDivide.setText("Dividir");
            btnMultiply.setText("Se multiplican");
            btnSubtract.setText("Reste");
            btnLanguage.setText("Idioma");
        }
    });
```

I also want to know if Windows automatically changes the text in programs to the system language.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really should have some kind of model, which your first class would change (some property), the model would the generate a notification, which the other three could listen for and take appropriate action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Swing has no good l10n support build in. You need to handle the labels renaming etc. yourself.

Usually, what swing supports, is the Java resource bundle concept, where you choose the resource with all the texts before the UI is build.

In your code, you will have then no more text messages, but you will get strings from your bundle.

Here you have 4 bundle files, named with an infix of at least the language you want.

```
# Bundle file lang.properties
button.addition.text=Add

# Bundle file lang_de.properties
button.addition.text=Addieren

# Bundle file lang_en.properties
button.addition.text=Add

# Bundle file lang_fr.properties
button.addition.text=Addition
```

In your code, you load the resource bundle before you build the ui (in a class called `App` for the example):

```
public static ResourceBundle R;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Locale l = new Locale(args[0], args[1]); // should have a check here :-)
   R = ResourceBundle.getBundle("l10n/lang.properties", l); 
}
```

When you init your UI, you will call use:

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.setText(App.R.getString("button.addition.text"));
```

This allows not to switch at runtime. Nevertheless, you could make use of Java8 lambdas and register all label carriers with a setter for the translated text on a `L10nService`.

```
public class L10nService {
    ResourceBundle R = .... // initialize or change at runtime

    private List<LabelSetter> setters = new ArrayList<LabelSetter>();

    public void addSetter(LabelSetter setter) {
        setters.add(setter);
    }

    public void changeLanguage(Locale l) {
        R = ResourceBundle.getBundle("l10n/lang", l);
        for(LabelSetter s : setters) {
             s.set(R);
        }
    }
}
```

In your UI, you will build the UI, and for each element to be translated, you register the LabelSetter:

```
void buildUi(L10nService fac, Locale l) {
    JButton btn = new JButton();
    LabelSetter s = R -> btn.setText(R.getText("button.addition.text"));
    fac.addSetter(s);

    // ... continue adding ui elements

   // when you are ready to build: 
   fac.changeLanguage(l);
}
```

Beware: This has drawbacks. While you can super-easy switch the language at runtime, you are keeping your UI elements in memory even when you destroyed the container they used to live in. This is because they are in the closure `LabelSetter`, that you have registered. As long as this closure exists, your UI objects will not go away. So, on destruction of UI elements, you need to make sure, you remove them from the `L10nService` as well. Additionally, swing could require massive repainting and relayouting if all the labels change. 
The benefit here is, that you can actually make the swing library aware of l10n changes with `ResourceBundles` and the language switch propagates itself.

Alternatively, you could implement a `L10nTextSource`, that emits `LocaleChangedEvents`. Your UI classes would listen to those events and rewrite themselves. The drawback here is, that you need to extend every UI element you want to add the functionality to or add the functionality at least to your components.